# Python PermissionError on some file operations

Tags: windows, python-3.x

I created the following Python 3.5 script:

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path

def test_unlink():
    log = Path('log.csv')

    fails = 0
    num_tries = int(sys.argv[1])
    for i in range(num_tries):
        try:
            log.write_text('asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf')

            with log.open('r') as logfile:
                lines = logfile.readlines()
                # Check the second line to account for the log file header
                assert len(lines) == 1

            log.unlink()
            not log.exists()

        except PermissionError:
            sys.stdout.write('! ')
            sys.stdout.flush()
            fails += 1

    assert fails == 0, '{:%}'.format(fails / num_tries)


test_unlink()
```

and run it like this: `python test.py 10000`. On Windows 7 Pro 64 with Python 3.5.2, the failure rate is not 0: it is small, but non-zero. Sometimes, it is not even that small: 5%! If you printout the exception, it will be this:

```
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\...\\log.csv'
```

but it will sometimes occur at the exists(), other times at the write_text(), and I wouldn't be surprised if it happens at the unlink() and the open() too.

Note that the same script, same Python (3.5.2), but on linux (through http://repl.it/), does not have this issue: failure rate is 0.

I realize that a possible workaround could be:

```
while True: 
    try: log.unlink()
    except PermissionError: pass
    else: break
```

but this is tedious and error prone (several methods on Path instance would need this, easy to forget), and should (IMHO) not be necessary, so I don't think it is practical solution.

So, does anyone have an explanation for this, and a practical workaround, maybe a mode flag somewhere that can be set when Python starts?

Comment: It's a synchronization failure in the file system, possibly related to a virus/malware scanner. WinAPI `DeleteFile` is implemented by opening a handle (a reference to a kernel `File` object), which is used to set the delete disposition on the underlying link control block in the file system. It doesn't actually unlink a file from a directory until all referencing kernel `File` objects have been closed. Until then, as long as the delete disposition is set, while you can see the file in the directory listing, you're denied access to open a new handle, even for just reading file attributes.

Comment: You could try subclassing `pathlib.Path` to wrap calling `unlink`. Call the `super()` method, and then loop on `os.stat` while it raises a `PermissionError`, but only with `winerror == 5` (access denied), not 32 (sharing violation).

Comment: Seems to me this should be handled by pathlib. I'll post on python-dev forum.

Comment: Did you try disabling all virus/malware scanners? A scanner may create an extra `File` handle to read the file. It would be opened with delete sharing, so normally it's not a problem, except in situations like this when a program expects to immediately reuse the name of a deleted file.

Comment: Thanks eryksun for your comments. I believe the corporate anti-virus cannot be turned off (*maybe* via msconfig), but it's worth a try just to see if that fixes the issue (clearly I cant be leaving going it off and stopping it every time I run a test suite that uses Path.unlink.